# IllegalStateException: Cannot show Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to show/hide a fragment. It works fine most of the time but very rarely I am getting a crash java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot show Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager.

I have a function to show/hide fragments in Activity.

```
private var previousFragment: Fragment? = null

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val backStateName = fragment.javaClass.name
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    if (!fragment.isAdded) {
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            fragmentTransaction
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragment, backStateName)
        }
    }

    if (previousFragment != null)
        fragmentTransaction.hide(previousFragment!!)

    fragmentTransaction.show(fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()

    previousFragment = fragment
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: First of all why do you use add and not replace?

Comment: Because I am using BottomNavigationView in activity

Comment: I also used bottomnavigation and never neded to use add when I wanted to replace fragments.

Comment: Can you show me code and what is wrong in add?

Comment: I have scrollview in fragment, If I use replace then fragment scroll back to top but if I use add then there is no issue with scollview

Answer (score 0):

As a starting code I would start from here:

```
    private var previousFragment: Fragment? = null


    private object mOnNavigationListener : OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.home -> return true
                R.id.fragmentA -> {
                    fragment = FragmentA()
                    replaceFragment(fragment)
                    return true
                }
                R.id.fragmentB -> {
                    fragment = FragmentB()
                    replaceFragment(fragment)
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }


    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        fragmentTransaction
          .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragment)
          .commit();

        previousFragment = fragment;
    }
```

Links to start: 
1. [Bottom Navigation View With Fragments (No fragment re-creation)](https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711)

2. [Bottom navigation](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#)

3. [Code Labs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#0) 
4. [Bottom Nav Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-tutorial/)

Comment: I used 1st link, it is also throwing same error sometimes